# How do I select the top third and bottom third items in excel

Tags: vba, excel

how do I select the top third and bottom third items from a list in excel

Comment: Why do you want to do this??  There's not much you can do with cells that aren't continuous.

Comment: what exactly is your definition of a "list" and do you mean to do this by VBA (programatically) or just using excel? do you want to do some calculation with these values? means you wouldn't need to literally `select` these items but you would want to find the cells of it, right? please provide more details! otherwise we won't be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Hold ctrl and then click each cell in the top and bottom third.

Answer (score 0):

You have not really explained your question or why you want to do this but based on tags I presume its in vba. So if you have 30 cells then something like:

```
Sub selectThirds()

   Union(Range("A1:A10"), Range("A20:A30")).Select

End Sub
```

If the number if cells was dynamic you could count the number of rows and divide by three.